# Put data from JSON in MySQL Database

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server, database, json

I have a question about JSON and MySQL Database.
What I want is that I can load the data from a JSON-file into my fields in my database.
My JSON-file looks like this:

```
{
    "wijken": {
        "11": {
            "id": "kml_1",
            "fid": "0",
            "wijziging": "Ja",
            "nieuwnr": "11",
            "naam": "Noordoost",
            "wijk": "Kanaaldorpen en -zone",
            "wijknr": "11",
            "objectid": "1",
            "area": "0",
            "len": "0"
        },
        "12": {
            "id": "kml_2",
            "fid": "1",
            "wijziging": "Ja",
            "nieuwnr": "12",
            "naam": "Noordoost",
            "wijk": "Oostakker",
            "wijknr": "12",
            "objectid": "2",
            "area": "0",
            "len": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a database with a table "wijken" with fields:

> ID / FID / WIJZIGING / NIEUWNR / NAAM / WIJK / WIJKNR / OBJECTID /
>   AREA / LEN

Now I want that all the data from the json-file comes in that table. (php + javascript)

Can someone help me start? (Or give a tutorial of some good search terms maybe)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at [json_decode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: PLease try to use english names in questions to make them easier to understand

Comment: you may also have a look at mongodb it allows you to store the data directly in json format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to load the file from the filesystem

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('some/path/to/file.json');
```

Then you can turn the json string into a php array using `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

At this point you will be able to access the data to go into the *wijken* table with `$data['wijken']`.

In order to insert this data into a mysql database, you will need to use one of the php mysql extensions, either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

I will use mysqli for this example:

```
// first create a connection to your database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database_name');

// this insert query defines the table, and columns you want to update
$query = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO wijken ('ID', 'FID', 'WIJZIGING', 'NIEUWNR', 'NAAM', 'WIJK', 'WIJKNR', 'OBJECTID', 'AREA', 'LEN')
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SQL;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

// for each of the 'rows' of data in the json we parsed, we will insert each value
// into it's corresponding column in the database, and we are doing this using prepared
// statements.
foreach ($data['wijken'] as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bind_param(
        // the types of the data we are about to insert: s = string, i = int
        'sissssiiii', 
        $value['id'],
        $value['fid'],
        $value['wijziging'],
        $value['nieuwnr'],
        $value['naam'],
        $value['wijk'],
        $value['wijknr'],
        $value['objectid'],
        $value['area'],
        $value['len']
    );

    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();

// close the connection to the database
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will output your json keys and values.

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```