# Json to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, json, facebook

I'm trying to parse a json file and push fields to database jSON Source : `http://graph.facebook.com/10153575791993298/`

Parsing and Echo

```
<?php
    $json_file = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/10153575791993298/');
    $info = json_decode($json_file);

    if ($info) {
         foreach ($info->likes->data as $obj){
            echo $obj->id, "<br/>";
            echo $obj->name, "<br/>";
         }
    }
?>
```

Database part :

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'facebook');
    $query = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO Likes ('ID', 'Name')
    VALUES (?, ?)
    SQL;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    foreach ($info['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bind_param(
            // the types of the data we are about to insert: s = string, i = int
            'ss', 
            $value['id'],
            $value['name'],
        );
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

I setup my tables correctly and I don't know why I can't push data to my database. 
Json part that I would like to retrieve data and push to my db `http://graph.facebook.com/10153575791993298/likes`

Comment: There is parse error in first code block, but I don't know if it's just copy&paste mistake.. Please debug your code and provide exact error message.

Comment: There shouldn't be any spaces around your ending heredoc delimiter. As Elon said; this will cause a parse error. Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php that will tell you. Plus, the quotes in `('ID', 'Name')` those are columns, not string values, so remove them. I'm tempted to make this an answer.

Comment: $data['data']; where is this variable coming from?

Comment: fixed parsing it was a copy/paste error thx for help

Comment: Marc has given you an answer below.

Comment: First of all, are you getting anything back from `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: yes my first block code working now, my problem is only the DB part I don't know why elements are not added in the db, I'm trying Marc solution now but I checked this topic too and they were doing same than me : [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295508/put-data-from-json-in-mysql-database

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but try removing the comma for the last `$value['name'],` <= maybe SQL doesn't like that. So change to `$value['name']`

Comment: Plus, you should check for errors. Change `$stmt->execute();` to `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Syntax 101: `'` turns things into strings:

```
INSERT INTO Likes ('ID', 'Name')
                   ^--^--^----^---
```

You're not inserting into a field named `ID`. You're passing in a **STRING**, which is illegal syntax. Once something's a string, it will NOT be interpreted as a field/table identifier by the DB.

It should be just

```
INSERT INTO Likes (ID, Name)
```

since neither of your fieldnames are reserved words. If you INSIST on quoting things, then use backticks for quoting field/table names:

```
INSERT INTO Likes (`ID`, `Name`)
```

Comment: What if OP's posted code is in fact what they're using. You've missed the fact about the heredoc, should it be the case. Just saying.

Comment: Maybe so, but if that extra indenting is not just a copy/paste artifact there, then the script itself would die with a unexpected EOF, since the heredoc never terminates.

Comment: True. However, you know just as well as I, that most people posting hardly check for errors ;-) Edit: it was a paste error. OP just said so (ain't it always the case?). *Carry on my Wayward Son* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you are using a quote in your insert query `INSERT INTO Likes ('ID', Name')`
the right syntax will be

```
INSERT INTO Likes (ID, Name)
```

Comment: thx for help and I think I made a mistake here : `foreach ($data['data'] as $key => $value)`

Comment: Best if luck in your current project.